# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #9: Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, error-handling

I am trying to learn Android from `head first Android` book , and this is one of it's codes, but I don't why it gives me this strange error? As I am new in Android couldn't solve the problem and posted it here. I don't know if this data enough or not? Detail activity is an activity that has a fragment on it's `.xml` file and points to a fragment activity with a layout includes two text view on it.

DetailActivity.java:

```
package com.example.m.workoutapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    }
}
```

activity_detail.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.m.workoutapp.DetailActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.m.workoutapp.WorkoutDetailFragment" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The error happens in this line: `android:name="com.example.m.workoutapp.WorkoutDetailFragment"`

WorkoutDetailFragment.java:

```
package com.example.m.workoutapp;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class WorkoutDetailFragment extends Fragment {


    public WorkoutDetailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_detail, container, false);
    }

}
```

fragment_workout_detail:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.m.workoutapp.WorkoutDetailFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="workout title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_desciption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="workout description"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Full error message:

```
01-30 21:38:45.386 25393-25393/com.example.m.workoutapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.m.workoutapp, PID: 25393
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.m.workoutapp/com.example.m.workoutapp.DetailActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #10: Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for com.example.m.workoutapp.WorkoutDetailFragment
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3385)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:378)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                              at com.example.m.workoutapp.DetailActivity.onCreate(DetailActivity.java:11)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire error stack trace here? Its being cut off in the title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in your `activity_detail.xml` file:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     tools:context="com.example.m.workoutapp.DetailActivity">
>
>     <fragment
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:name="com.example.m.workoutapp.WorkoutDetailFragment" />
>
> </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
> ```

When you use the `<fragment>` tag, the system will automatically create an instance of your `WorkoutDetailFragment` and add it to the activity's `FragmentManager`. To do this, the system needs some way to identify your fragment to the fragment manager. You have three choices:

1. Add an `android:id` attribute to the `<fragment>` tag's parent (the `ConstraintLayout`)
2. Add an `android:id` attribute to the `<fragment>` tag itself
3. Add an `android:tag` attribute to the `<fragment>` tag itself

Any of these will allow the fragment manager to identify and track the fragment, which will solve your crash.

It doesn't even really matter what `tag` or `id` you use, either (though it's always good to pick descriptive names). As long as you don't re-use the id or tag somewhere else in your activity's layout, it will be fine.